# Unable to attach masterpage to Page Layout

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage, sharepoint-designer

I am editing a page layout in SP Designer 2010. For whatever reason, the option to Attach (or Detach) a master page to my page layout is greyed out.  Does anyone have any insight on why this option is not available? [It previously worked on other page layouts.]   The Page Layout type is a Wiki page.

Additionally, there is a custom masterpage in the library (one that I did not make), which I wanted to edit.  However, when I go to edit it in Advanced Mode, I am unable to see all of the Sharepoint Controls that are contained inside of it.  It stops after the ASP module for the main Place Holder (PlaceHolderMain).  It's based on the v4 masterpage from what I can tell.

Thanks.

Comment: I've got a similar issue except I can select MP but it just won't attach. Did you ever resolve this?